# Gerrit Label - Verified

Tags: gerrit

I have gerrit up and running I have committed my first initial change. However, I can only see the Code Review on the Review page. I went to the access page for All-Projects (from which my project inherits its ACLs) and added the Label Verify for administrators. I log into the administrator account but am unable to verify my change and push. Below is a screen shots of what I think to be correct configuration, and a screen shot of the verify label not appearing.

What is the correct way to get the verify label to show up so I can push my change?

[image: Project Access]
[image: No Verify Label]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you put the `label-Verified` line in the `refs/meta/config` stanza. It needs to be in `refs/heads/*` or similar.

`[access "refs/heads/*"]
        label-Verified = -1..+1 group Administrators`

for example.

Answer (score 3):

You need to manually add the change to have the Verified option. You may follow the below options:

```
mkdir tmp
cd tmp
git init
git remote add origin ssh://admin@remote.site.com:29418/All-Projects
git fetch origin refs/meta/config:refs/remotes/origin/meta/config
git checkout meta/config
```

No you will be able to see **project.config** file.
Keep the below block to that file:

```
[label "Verified"]
       function = MaxWithBlock
       value = -1 Fails
       value =  0 No score
       value = +1 Verified
```

Now commit and push this change to remote.

```
git commit -a
git push origin meta/config:meta/config
```

That's all, now you will be able to see the **Verified** option as well.

Comment: This is the correct way to do it, according to the documentation. https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-labels.html#label_Verified